# How to use the "handler" of UIAlertAction to call another UIAlertAction?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to use the handler to trigger other alerts?

```
func jokeFinal() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Never Mind", message: "It's Pointless", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Hahahahahaha", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func joke() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "A broken pencil", message: "...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "A broken pencil who?", style: .default, handler: jokeFinal())
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func nock() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Knock,Knock", message: "..", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Who's there??", style: .default, handler: joke())
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm trying to use the handler of a `UIAlertAction` to call another `UIAlert`. Is it possible?

I am receiving the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course! It's possible. Try something like that:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Title", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.someFunction()
}))
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here's your function:

```
func someFunction() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Some Title", message: "Some Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Title For Button", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        // Completion block
    }))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's your problem line:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Who's there??", style: .default, handler: joke())
```

You can easily change it to:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Who's there??", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        // Completion block
})
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The handler doesn't *call* a function. It *is* a function.

So, for example, you might do this. Change the declaration of

```
 func jokeFinal() {
```

to

```
 func jokeFinal(_ action: UIAlertAction) {
```

Then change

```
 handler: jokeFinal()
```

to

```
 handler: jokeFinal
```

And so on.

Comment: may I know what do to if I wanted to add a parameter to pass to the function?