# Updating UILabel from UIAlertAction handler not working in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have a subclass of UITableView in my iOS app (Swift 4, XCode 9). This table has one row and I want it to display an alert when it's clicked, get some input from the user, and then update a label (`lblUserFromPrefs`) in the table when the user clicks "OK" in the alert. Currently everything works fine except the label doesn't get updated. Here is the relevant code from my UITableView subclass:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Clicked section: \(indexPath.section) row: \(indexPath.row)")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Username", message: "what is your name", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.text = ""
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        let textField = alert!.textFields![0]
        if let text = textField.text {
            print("Text field: \(text)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.lblUserFromPrefs.text = text
                print("label updated")
            }
        }
    }))

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What happens when I run this is the label's text doesn't change when the alert closes but does change immediately when the table row is clicked again. I don't know why it waits until the row is clicked again to update the text. All the print statements print when I expect (including printing "label updated" immediately when the alert's OK button is pressed) and they print the right things. I know that when you're trying to update the UI from a closure in a background thread you have to use `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` but I'm not sure why it's not updating even though I am using the main thread. I have tried using `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {})` and putting `self.lblUserFromPrefs.setNeedsDisplay()` directly after `self.lblUserFromPrefs.text = "text"`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: You don’t need to call `DispatchQueue`, anyway your problem looks like `[weak alert]`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47361979/6680583)

Comment: @Mannopson I removed the DispatchQueue wrapping and changed `[weak alert]` to `(action) in` but it's still behaving the same way. What exactly from that link should I look at? I'm not trying to call an alert from this alert, I just can't get this UILabel to update at the right time. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `[weak self]` to the dispatch like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

}
```

Comment: @CoryMatthews I copied your code and it worked so the issue is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Enter some text", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in

        // Text field configuration
        textField.placeholder = "Enter..."
        textField.text = ""
    }

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        if (alertController.textFields?.first?.hasText)! {
            if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
                self.label.text = text // Update the value
            }
        } else {
            self.label.text = "" // Default value
        }
    }))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) // Present alert controller
```

Comment: Sadly still the same behavior.

Comment: I think the issue is coming from using static cells in the UITableView but I'm not sure how to update a UILabel in a static UITableView in real time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for the behavior you want to achieve. Just include your alert controller code in didSelect and you should be good to go!

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UITableViewController {

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    if cell == nil {
      cell = UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text = "Hello World!"
    return cell!
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Hello Universe!"
  }
}
```