# How to update UILabel in a static UITableView when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created an iOS app (XCode 9, Swift 4) with the only view being a table view set to "Static Cells". The view controller of this table is connected to a custom subclass of UITableViewController, whose code I'm including below. The table has one section and that section has one row. Inside this row is a label whose text is initially "Label" and the label is connected to the IBOutlet in my custom view controller. [Here is what the storyboard looks like, for the more visually minded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hu1R.png)

My custom Table View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.label.text = "changed"
        print("cell clicked")
    }
}
```

Right now, when the cell with the label in it is tapped, "cell clicked" is printed, but the text doesn't change. When the cell is tapped again, "cell clicked" is printed again, the cell becomes selected, and the label's text does become "changed".

Ideally, the label would change its text to "changed" immediately when the cell it's in is tapped, but it doesn't and I can't figure out why. I was thinking it might have something to do with the label not being updated/redrawn even though its text is changing, because when I click the label and then scroll the view, the label's text becomes "changed" right when I start scrolling. I tried wrapping `self.label.text = changed` with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` to see if anything would change, but it doesn't.

For context, this is a simplified case of a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452201/updating-uilabel-from-uialertaction-handler-not-working-in-swift-4) and I boiled down the issue (as far as I can tell) to this simple case. Does anyone have any ideas for what I can do? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update any property of a cell on didSelect, you first need to get the reference to that cell and then update its properties:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
cell?.textLabel?.text = "New value"
cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Some other value"
```

You don't need any IBOutlet here.
If you're using custom cell, then you can have IBOutlet in your UITableViewCell subclass and then you can get the cell reference (as above) and can modify any custom cell properties.

Comment: I didn't have a custom cell class but I just made a class `MyTableViewCell` with an IBOutlet named `label` connected to the label and made the cell a member of that class. My Controller class now says `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell` and
            `cell.label?.text = "New value"` but I'm still getting the same behavior. Is this what you meant?

Comment: See this gist - [link](https://gist.github.com/swapniljain23/051a30a3215616ca3860192165fd73e2) This just works fine in playground for me. You can do similar with custom cell as well.

Comment: Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/swapniljain23/bdd1f7732229578de786fd4bf91825a1) with custom cell sample code.

Comment: Well, my machine is having trouble with playground but I pasted the code into a new project and it's the same issue. I'm stumped now and I'll need to do a bit of redesigning but thanks so much for all the help!!!